# sabe alguien como puedo integrar Bootstrap a nodejs con Express?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, nodejs, express

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación usando **nodejs** y el framework **Express**.
Quiero agregar **Bootstrap** a mi proyecto en modo local.
agregué esto a mi índice  (ya teniendo descargado Bootstrap)

```
<script language = "javascript" src = "- / node_modules / bootstrap / dist / js / bootstrap.min.js"> </ script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./ node_modules / bootstrap / dist / css / bootstrap.min.css" />
```

descubrí que tengo que agregar este código a mi app.js

```
app.use (express.static (__ dirname + '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));
```

pero tampoco funciona
(Tengo en mente el camino de Bootstrap y uso '../ modules ...' también.
alguien sabe como puedo usarlo o tiene un ejemplo?

Comment: Saludos, checa esto a ver si te sirve en algo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAUncPg_FVw

Comment: gracias por el video

Comment: Tengo una guía de como usar bootstrap con nodejs
https://www.paraprogramador.com/tutorial/usar-el-sass-de-bootstrap-con-node-js/
espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizo bootstraps de esta manera:

1. Creo una carpeta como por ejemplo 'data_lib'
2. Agrego al archivo  app.js:

   app.use('/data_lib', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'data_lib')));

El (path.join o path.resolve) para tratar las rutas absolutas aqui puedes leer mas sobre esto [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110801/path-join-vs-path-resolve-with-dirname)

3. Descargo el bootstrap directamente desde el navegador y lo copio dentro de esta carpeta.
4. Para llamarlo desde tu archivo desde tu vista o  (indice) lo haces de esta manera:

```html
<script language = "javascript" src = "/data_lib/ bootstrap / dist /js /bootstrap.min.js"> </ script> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="/data_lib/ bootstrap / dist / css / bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Te conviene usar `bootstrap-sass` con un task manager como Gulp. Suena complicado, pero es sencillo.

Podes carpeta `dev` donde pones los estilos y el código javascript y hacer que eso traspile a una carpeta en el front junto a los HTML que se llame por ejemplo `statics`.

```
├── dev
|   ├── styles // acá metes los sass
|   └── js

├── statics
|   ├── fonts
|   ├── img
|   ├── css
|   └── js
```

Despues de eso, te quedarían las llamadas así:

```
<script type="javascript" src="statics/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "statics/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Las rutas usando `node_modules` te van a funcionar sólo de forma local.

Comment: como traspilo el bootstrap.min.js?